# Add a default validator to my custom UIComponent

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, validation, custom-component

I am developing a custom JSF UIInput which will expect a specially crafted value from the user. In order to validate the user input, I need to run a series of checks which relate only the application at hand. It's not just a normal email, or phonenumber input field. It's a text input which has a composite value that needs to be deconstructed into parts and each part needs to be validated.

I managed to create the component itself.

```
@FacesComponent("MyComponent")
public class MyComponent extends UIInput {
   public String getFamily() {...}

   encodeBegin() {...}
   encodeEnd() {...}

}
```

`mycomponent.taglib.xml` is bundled inside `META-INF` and I can use and test the component successfully.

I also have a validator class implemented which does all the work. It's ready.

```
public class AutomationDetectionValidator implements Validator {
   public void validate(...) throws ValidatorException {...}
}
```

However, I need to include a custom validator to this component as a default. I can do this manually as follows:

```
<custom:myComponent>
    <f:validator validatorId=”myComponentValidator”/>
</custom:myComponent>
```

But the expected usage would be

```
<custom:myComponent/>
```

And the validator should be there automatically.

I've been googling all day now, but I can find are basic examples of the usage we don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it in component's constructor.

```
public MyComponent() {
    addValidator(new AutomationDetectionValidator());
}
```

Comment: As a side note, I had my code updated locally here and I missed the simple fact that the addValidator() method is inherited directly from UIInput. You won't see this method if you are extending from UIComponent. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. It's indeed definied in `UIInput` which you've already there in your question.